# Uploading a file in react native

Tags: file, react-native

How can I upload a file in react-native in the most easy way to the server?
There is online too much information and libraries, thus I don't know if they're safe to use.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the method to upload file to server using `fetch`

```
        const body = new FormData();

        //String Key value pair appending to body   
        body.append('KEY', VALUE);
        body.append('KEY', VALUE);
        body.append('KEY', VALUE);

        //Appending file to body
        body.append(KEY_AS REQUIRED_IN_SERVICE, {
                uri: PASS_URI_OF_THE_FILE,
                type: 'image/jpeg', //This is the file type .. you can define according to your requirement
                name: 'photo.jpg',   //File name you want to pass
            })
        //Service call                        
        fetch(YOUR_URL, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: new Headers({
                YOUR_HEADER_PARAMS
            }),
            body: body
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {

               //GET RESPONSE SUCCESS OF FAILURE

            })
            .catch((error) => {
               //ERROR 
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

give a try https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs

we use in production in some apps

Comment: I installed this library but unfortunately after that I couldn't built the emulator, 
So I had to uninstall.

Comment: ouch, and find you another library?

Comment: I really not sure what to use, I prefer without libraries but I don't know how